# Asking for funding opportunities for phd in France if a professor has said yes to me but his university doesn't have any doctoral scholarship

Tags: phd, mathematics, funding, france

I am a masters of mathematics student in India and a professor to whom I  mailed my CV has said his Institute doesn't have a doctoral scholarship at the moment but he will be happy to supervise my thesis if I get funding from other organizations.

> So, I want to ask can somebody please tell about to which organizations I should ask for funding opportunities.
>
> My family is allowing me to self fund my phd  and after that I am thinking I would also do part time work as per my spare time. But do French Institutions allow doctorate student to work along with Phd thesis and also do phd students in mathematics get enough spare time that they can do some part time job.

Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46474/phd-part-time-vs-full-time

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42076/part-time-phd-workload-compared-to-part-time-undergrad-workload

Comment: If they can't provide funding you shouldn't be getting your PhD there.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist that is not entirely true. Perhaps Dxdxdade have some access to external financial support in which case I see no reason to decline the offer.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Cant I work part time in my spare time and get a part of funding from my parents ? Does institutes in france allows that?

Comment: @BoatyMcboatface Does french institutes allow me to work part time ?

Comment: @Dxdxdade probably not. I am not sure though. Do you speak fluent French? If so you can probably ask the mathematician.

Comment: Even if you can, you shouldn't.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist Why shouldn't I?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/is-it-worth-self-funding-a-phd-to-attend-a-top-10-university

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do a PhD part time in France. Or rather, it is possible to have a full time job and do a PhD on the side. You will not get a part time doctoral contract. This is common in social sciences or the humanities. In math, this is also common when school teachers want to get a PhD for various reasons, e.g. teach in a university or in a higher preparatory school (or just for the heck of it).

One of the main downside is, of course, that your PhD is going to take *much* longer than the three years standard. Six years would be a more reasonable target; PhDs can take a decade to complete in humanities.

Let me mention that self-funding is not an option. If you do not have a doctoral contract (aka PhD-related funding), doctoral schools will ask for proof of income.

But you should reread your potential advisor's email. From what you have told us, it does not appear to say that he is willing to be your advisor if you do a PhD part time. This is a completely different promise than saying he is willing to be your advisor if you find funding. You should clarify this with him but I am unsure that you will like the answer.

The best person to ask about funding opportunities is your potential advisor. Without knowing details (what university, what field) it is impossible to answer beyond vague generalities. This is too dependent on local factors such as how many stipends do the ministry or local governments give out, companies that may be willing to cofund PhDs, local fellowships, and so on. You can ask your potential advisor again, but if the first reply was already that they do not have funding, then I would wager that you are out of luck.

Comment: thanks a lot for such a clear reply. I am asking that is it possible that I work at some restaurant / some other work only on days when I don't have burden of study but I only want to do a phd thesis full time ie in 3 years. I would take some part time job on weekends for some hours so that my family doesn't have enough burden because of me.

Comment: I have been offered a phd position in Jean Monett University in number theory field.